# Tag synonym request: birds -> avian

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-tag, tag-synonyms

We currently have the general [avian](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avian), which for a long time has been described (in terms of the tag wiki excerpt) as

> For questions about birds and birdlike creatures.

After a recent edit by yours truly, it is now described as

> For questions about birds and birdlike creatures. Does not include machines designed for flying (consider [airships], [aircraft], [spaceships]). Consider also [flight].

However, there is currently no tag [birds](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/birds)

**I propose that `birds` is established as a tag synonym, with the canonical tag being `avian`** as `birds` is more discoverable, but `avian` is more generic.

See also discussion on [the factory floor, beginning here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31717523#31717523) (link to the chat transcript).

Comment: I've noticed you've been doing a lot of work with the tags of late. Boredom, or just thought it needed to be done?

Comment: @Frostfyre Just been looking through some of our tags, checking to see if I felt any clean-up needed to be done, and found some things I felt could be improved upon so proposed appropriate edits (and in one case raised a moderator flag which had an outcome I didn't quite anticipate, requiring further editing).

Comment: Thanks for your work on improving our tagging!  (And if that unexpected outcome from a mod flag was me, sorry about that -- I didn't notice whatever the extra editing was that you had to do.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Don't know if that was you, but the extra editing came from a tag being deleted instead of renamed which would have been more proper (would have kept the tag wiki).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling oops.  Which deleted tag?  I can look for it in the orphaned tag wikis, unless you've already replaced it.

Comment: @MonicaCellio airplane, I think.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling was it this?  (It was your edit, so probably.) "For questions involving heavier-than-air objects designed to fly in an atmosphere, including airplanes and helicopters. Not for flight-capable living creatures (consider [avian]). Compare [flight], [airships] and [shapeships]."

Comment: @MonicaCellio Might be (I don't really remember). Don't worry much about it. :)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Would you be willing to post an answer saying this has been resolved, so there is something to accept?

Comment: Probably not strictly required given the status-completed tag, but sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[birds](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/birds) is now a synonym of [avian](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avian).